# Is it possible to set the id with a value via curl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, curl

When curling my own app, via:

```
curl -i -X HEAD http://www.foo.com
```

And in the action that loads the page, I have:

```
puts request.session_options
```

In the logs I see:

```
:path=>"/", :domain=>:all, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :secret=>"dsfiuasfiusioufuioasifaiosudfiouasioufiouas123", :coder=>#<Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64::Marshal:0x007fe070b89108>, :id=>nil}
```

Is it possible to set the `:id` with a value via curl? So it looks like:

```
:path=>"/", :domain=>:all, :expire_after=>nil, :secure=>false, :httponly=>true, :defer=>false, :renew=>false, :secret=>"dsfiuasfiusioufuioasifaiosudfiouasioufiouas123", :coder=>#<Rack::Session::Cookie::Base64::Marshal:0x007fe070b89108>, :id=>"foobar"}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be curling something like `http://www.foo.com?id=1234`?

Comment: Im trying to set something in `request.session_options`, not `request.params`

Comment: what is your basic idea of overwriting the Rack::Session ID? in my opinion, that doenst make sense.

Comment: @huan son im wondering if curl is capable of doing that. making sense is another thing

Comment: its not a lack of curl. curl just sends http requests, however u design it. u need to hack that into the Rack::Session Class by yourself.

Comment: @huan son, not sure if it is necessary to hack Rack::Session. You will notice that `puts request.session_options[:id]` will always be different whenever you clear your browser cookies and refresh your page. If such a thing can happen via the browser, then curl should be able to do it. Basically, is there a way to tell curl to visit a page as a new "user" every time?